# Liquibase does not throw an error when I manually change database structure

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, liquibase

I have a simple, typical spring boot application which uses PostgreSQL database.

Here is my **Item.java** entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    public UUID id;

    private String name;

    private LocalDate added;

    private boolean available;

}
```

Here are my liquibase scripts (in separate *.sql files):

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset author:001
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item (
    id        UUID                    NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_item PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    name      VARCHAR UNIQUE          NOT NULL,
    added     DATE DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL,
    available BOOLEAN   DEFAULT TRUE  NOT NULL
);

--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset author:002
INSERT INTO item (name, available) VALUES ('item1', TRUE);
INSERT INTO item (name, available) VALUES ('item2', TRUE);
INSERT INTO item (name, available) VALUES ('item3', FALSE);
INSERT INTO item (name, available) VALUES ('item4', TRUE);
INSERT INTO item (name, available) VALUES ('item5', TRUE);
INSERT INTO item (name, available) VALUES ('item6', TRUE);
INSERT INTO item (name, available) VALUES ('item7', FALSE );
INSERT INTO item (name, available) VALUES ('item8', FALSE );
INSERT INTO item (name, available) VALUES ('item9', FALSE );
INSERT INTO item (name, available) VALUES ('item10', TRUE);
```

And my **application.yml** file

```
spring:

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate

  liquibase:
    change-log: liquibase/master.xml
    enabled: true
```

Ok, now let us consider that I want manually change or add any column to my database structure.

I am adding the field **"description"** to my **Item.java** entity:

```
private String description;
```

and adding the same column directly to database (**without making new liquibase changesets**):

```
ALTER TABLE item ADD description VARCHAR(255);
```

Now, I am running my application and expecting an error like:

```
Validation Failed:
 1 change sets check sum
com/example/changelog.xml::1::example was: 8:63f82d4ff1b9dfa113739b7f362bd37d but is now: 8:b4fd16a20425fe377b00d81df722d604
```

BUT.. nothing happens... My application runs absolutely normaly:

```
2023-06-18T11:44:32.214+02:00  INFO 9832 --- [  restartedMain] liquibase.database                       : Set default schema name to public
2023-06-18T11:44:32.257+02:00  INFO 9832 --- [  restartedMain] liquibase.lockservice                    : Successfully acquired change log lock
2023-06-18T11:44:32.405+02:00  INFO 9832 --- [  restartedMain] liquibase.changelog                      : Reading from public.databasechangelog
2023-06-18T11:44:32.439+02:00  INFO 9832 --- [  restartedMain] liquibase.lockservice                    : Successfully released change log lock
2023-06-18T11:44:32.479+02:00  INFO 9832 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-06-18T11:44:32.507+02:00  INFO 9832 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-06-18T11:44:32.632+02:00  INFO 9832 --- [  restartedMain] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2023-06-18T11:44:32.741+02:00  INFO 9832 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.c.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator   : Error calling `jakarta.validation.Validation#buildDefaultValidatorFactory`
```

I need to fix it and prevent any **manual changings** in my database structure. Only via adding new further changesets. How to implement it? Thank you!